# Matrix Division

Tags: matrices, recreational-mathematics, matrix-exponential

Somebody said matrix division isn’t a thing and there’s nothing I hate more than being told that something in maths or physics can’t be invented to meet that specific goal or result. In this case I was told division isn’t a thing but I know that I can exponentiate a matrix. Now e^A is in itself a matrix if A is an n by n matrix. This is likewise for e^B. Now we know how to deal with e^A/e^B this is just e^(A-B) and what we notice is that we just defined the division of matrices very nicely through the concept of exponentiation. My question is, would this work?

Comment: Isn't "dividing" a matrix A by a matrix B just multiplying A into the inverse of B?

Comment: We define matrix division as a form of multiplication, not exponentiation. And the idea is very simple. When dividing by 2, we instead multiply by 0.5, We call the reciprocal of 2 being 0.5. In matrix-land the reciprocal is the inverse. So multiplying by an inverse is in a way "dividing". And for multiplication we have a system

Comment: What do you mean by "would this work"?

Comment: Division as a binary operation isn't really done in higher math at all. You can use Euclidean division in Euclidean domains but even arithmetic in the rationals does away with division preferring to multiply by inverses instead. The main reason for this is that division is not associative while multiplication is.

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with [tag:division-algebras]. Please check the meaning of an unfamiliar tag before using it.

Comment: About your question. You seem to think that $e^{A-B}e^B=e^A$ holds for square matrices. This is not always true. For it to hold with certainty you need $AB=BA$. Also, not every matrix $M$ has the form $M=e^A$. This is already because $\det(e^A)$ is always non-zero, but we may have $\det M=0$.